# Suggestions for performance improvement in Julia

Tags: performance, julia

I'm making my first effort to move from Matlab to Julia and have found my code to improve by ~3x but still think there is more to come, I'm not using any global variables in the function and have preallocated all the arrays used (I think?). If there was any thoughts on how it could be sped up even further it would be greatly appreciated, I'll fully convert even at the current improvement I think!

```
function word_sim(tau::Int, omega::Int, mu::Float64)
# inserts a word in position (tau+1), at each point creates a new word with prob mu
# otherwise randomly chooses a previously used. Runs the program until time omega

words = zeros(Int32, 1, omega) # to store the words
tests = rand(1,omega) # will compare mu to these
words[1] = 1; # initialize the words
next_word = 2 # will be the next word used
words[tau+1] = omega + 1; # max possible word so insert that at time tau
innovates = mu .> tests; # when we'll make a new word
for i = 2:tau # simulate the process
    if innovates[i] == 1 # innovate 
        words[i] = next_word
        next_word = next_word + 1
    else # copy
        words[i] = words[rand(1:(i-1))]
    end
end
# force the word we're interested in
for i = (tau+2):omega
    if innovates[i] == 1 # innovate 
        words[i] = next_word
        next_word = next_word + 1
    else # copy
        words[i] = words[rand(1:(i-1))]
    end
end
result = sum(words .== (omega + 1)); # count how many times our word occurred
return result
end
```

and when I run it with these values it takes ~.26 seconds on my PC

```
using Statistics
@time begin
nsim = 10^3;
omega = 100;
seed = [0:1:(omega-1);]; 
mu = 0.01; 

results = zeros(Float64, 1, length(seed));
pops = zeros(Int64, 1, nsim);
for tau in seed
    for jj = 1:nsim
        pops[jj] = word_sim(tau, omega, mu);
    end
    results[tau+1] = mean(pops);
end
end
```

Or perhaps I'd be better writing the code in C++? Julia was my first reaction as I've heard rave reviews about its syntax, which to be honest is fantastic!

Any comments greatly appreciated.

Comment: Weird. Your code takes 0.371064 seconds on my computer. What version of Julia are you running? Any more details?

Comment: You might want to consider posting these more open ended performance question at discourse.julialang.org rather than on SO, there's usually people around that are happy to give performance tips

Comment: @StefanKarpinski yes, a decimal point is missing from the question it is 0.26, apologies.

Comment: @NilsGudat - thanks for the info I hadn't heard of that site previously.

Comment: It looks like the code block you are timing is making use of non-constant global variables and a global `for` loop. This is almost guaranteed to be slow.

Comment: xref: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/best-way-to-optimize-code/37980

Comment: Don't run something in the global scope. At least, encapsulate your the second part of your code in a main() function, and run this one

Answer (score 0):

A 3x speedup is a nice start, but it turns out there are a few more things you can do to improve performance significantly!

As a starting point, using your example posted above in Julia 1.6.1, I get

```
  0.301665 seconds (798.10 k allocations: 164.778 MiB, 12.70% gc time)
```

That's a lot of allocations, and a fair amount of garbage collector ("gc") time, so it seems we're producing a fair amount of garbage here. Some of the culprits are lines like

```
tests = rand(1,omega) # will compare mu to these
```

or

```
innovates = mu .> tests; # when we'll make a new word
```

In languages like Matlab or Python, pre-calculating these things whole-vector-at-a-time can be good for performance, but in Julia it's generally not really necessary, and can even hurt because each of these lines is causing a brand new array to be allocated. If we remove these and just generate our tests on the fly, we can avoid these allocations. One other line that allocates in here is

```
result = sum(words .== (omega + 1))
```

where you first build a whole new array before taking the sum of it. You could avoid this by writing it as a `for` loop (even though this may feel wrong coming from Matlab, it's *quite* fast in Julia). Or, to keep it as a one-liner, use either `count` or `sum` with a function that does the comparison as the first argument

```
result = count(x->(x == omega+1), words)
```

(in this example, just using an anonymous function `x->(x == omega+1)`).

Adding up these changes so far then

```
function word_sim(tau::Int, omega::Int, mu::Float64)
    # inserts a word in position (tau+1), at each point creates a new word with prob mu
    # otherwise randomly chooses a previously used. Runs the program until time omega
    words = zeros(Int32, 1, omega) # to store the words
    words[1] = 1; # initialize the words
    next_word = 2 # will be the next word used
    words[tau+1] = omega + 1; # max possible word so insert that at time tau
    for i = 2:tau # simulate the process
        if mu > rand()  # innovate
            words[i] = next_word
            next_word = next_word + 1
        else # copy
            words[i] = words[rand(1:(i-1))]
        end
    end
    # force the word we're interested in
    for i = (tau+2):omega
        if mu > rand() # innovate
            words[i] = next_word
            next_word = next_word + 1
        else # copy
            words[i] = words[rand(1:(i-1))]
        end
    end
    result = count(x->(x == omega+1), words) # count how many times our word occurred
    return result
end
```

Using the same timing code, this now brings us down to

```
  0.177766 seconds (298.10 k allocations: 51.863 MiB, 13.01% gc time)
```

So about half the time and half the allocations. There's still more though!
First, let's move the allocation of the `words` array outside of the word_sim function and instead make an in-place version of that function. We can also speed things up a adding an @inbounds to the tight `for` loops.

```
function word_sim!(words::AbstractArray, tau::Int, omega::Int, mu::Float64)
    # inserts a word in position (tau+1), at each point creates a new word with prob mu
    # otherwise randomly chooses a previously used. Runs the program until time omega
    fill!(words, 0) # Probably not necessary actually, but I haven't spent enough time looking at the code to be sure
    words[1] = 1; # initialize the words
    next_word = 2 # will be the next word used
    words[tau+1] = omega + 1; # max possible word so insert that at time tau
    @inbounds for i = 2:tau # simulate the process
        if mu > rand()  # innovate
            words[i] = next_word
            next_word = next_word + 1
        else # copy
            words[i] = words[rand(1:(i-1))]
        end
    end
    # force the word we're interested in
    @inbounds for i = (tau+2):omega
        if mu > rand() # innovate
            words[i] = next_word
            next_word = next_word + 1
        else # copy
            words[i] = words[rand(1:(i-1))]
        end
    end
    result = count(x->(x == omega+1), words) # count how many times our word occurred
    return result
end
```

In-place functions that modify one of their input arguments are usually denoted by a `!` at the end of their name by convention in Julia, hence the new function name.

Since we have to modify the timing code a bit to pre-allocate `words` now, let's also take the opportunity to put that timing code into a function to avoid any globals in the timing.

```
function run_word_sim()
    nsim = 10^3
    omega = 100
    seed = [0:1:(omega-1);]
    mu = 0.01

    results = zeros(Float64, 1, length(seed))
    pops = zeros(Int64, 1, nsim)
    words = zeros(Int32, 1, omega) # to store the words
    for tau in seed
        for jj = 1:nsim
            pops[jj] = word_sim!(words, tau, omega, mu)
        end
        results[tau+1] = mean(pops)
    end
    return results
end
```

Then get the most accurate timing results (and optionally some useful plots and statistics) we can use the BenchmarkTools package and its `@btime` or `@benchmark` macros

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime run_word_sim()
  124.178 ms (4 allocations: 10.17 KiB)
```

or
[image: Benchmark result with histogram and statistics]

So, almost another 3x speedup, and reduced allocations and memory usage (by four or five orders of magnitude) down to only the four arrays used in the timing code (`seed`, `results`, `pops` and `words`).

For the absolute maximum performance, you could possibly go even farther with [LoopVectorization.jl](https://github.com/JuliaSIMD/LoopVectorization.jl) and its `@turbo` macro, though it would likely require a change in algorithm since these loops depend on previous state, so don't appear to be compatible with loop re-ordering. You could turn the `count` into a for loop and `@turbo` that for a slight additional speedup though.

There are also other options for potentially faster random number generation, such as [VectorizedRNG.jl](https://github.com/chriselrod/VectorizedRNG.jl) as discussed in the discourse thread linked in the comments. While allocating a new vector of random numbers on each call of `word_sim` is likely not optimal, RNG *is* generally faster when you can generate a lot of random numbers at once, so passing a pre-allocated buffer of random numbers to `word_sim!` and filling that in-place with `rand!` as provided by either the `Random` stdlib or `VectorizedRNG` could yield a significant additional speedup.

Some of the tricks and rules of thumb used in this answer are discussed more generally in https://github.com/brenhinkeller/JuliaAdviceForMatlabProgrammers, along with a few other general Matlab -> Julia tips.